# accessory fill flash for nikon DSLR

Tags: flash

My nikon d3100 has broken flash... what can I use to replace it, externally?  I just want something small and lightweight, as fill flash. I have a large external flash unit, but it's HEAVY.
Thanks!
Claudia

Comment: [SB-400](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Flashes/SB-400-Speedlight-Unit.html) is probably what you're looking for, given that you already have a full-size speedlight.

Answer (score 1):

Get a smaller, lighter external flash unit.  They come in more than one size and you should be able to find one that fits your needs.  As an added bonus, it will still probably work better than your original built in flash.